# How to implement back navigation button in TableViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I', struggling with such issue- I can't add back-button to the last tableViewconrler.
When I'm tying to drag nav. item, but nothing happened.
How can I make this famous checkmark back element?

[image]

Comment: Your first tableview controller needs to be embedded in the navigation controller, rather that the second one.  Delete the navigation controller.  Select the first, select "Editor->Embed In->Navigation controller" then connect the first table view controller to the other one

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks! That exactly what I wanted to do!

Answer (score 0):

What they mean is your storyboard should look like this.

[image: Storyboard]